# Where can I define the body for a private function?

Tags: c++

I have a header like this (header guards not shown):

```
class GameSystem
{
public:
    GameSystem(Game *pcGame);
    virtual ~GameSystem();
    void Setup();
private:
    void InitGame();
    void RunGame();
    void ExitGame();
    Game *m_pcGame;

    /* Properties */
    int m_nWidth;
    int m_nHeight;
    int m_nFps;
    bool m_bFullscreen;
};
```

Where can I define the body for `InitGame()`, `RunGame()` and `ExitGame()`? Can I define it in my `.cpp` file? If so, how? Or am I obliged to make their body in my `.h` file?

I'm using Eclipse and I began typing: `void GameSystem::` and then it doesn't suggest the private functions.

Comment: The IDE is there to serve you, not to tell you what to do.

Comment: The accessibility of a method doesn't matter here. Whether it is public, private or protected shouldn't influence your decision to define your methods in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the non-question, I'm a java developer who has been moved over to a c++ project and this helped me out!

Comment: You could have simply _tried_ it instead of stopping when the auto-complete failed! People rely far too much on their IDEs nowadays #smh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes of course, but this question was like 4.5 years ago. I was 15 years old and a total C++ newbie.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I more or less ignore question timestamps as irrelevant when commenting/critiquing, except for technical reasons. :) Anyway, I was merely explaining a downvote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ye sure :) I would probably consider a downvote myself today as well for "shown not enough effort" or something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can define then in a .cpp file.  Just put `#include "MyHeader.h"` at the beginning of the file.  You'll also need to start each function like so

```
void GameSystem::Init(){
     //stuff
}
```

Comment: But `Setup()` isn't the problem. How to define the private functions?

Comment: same way, really.  Just include the header file.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: Exactly the same way as with `Setup()`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was confused by Eclipse his suggestion. It works perfect. I though: "Eclipse doesn't suggest it, so it would be wrong"

Answer (score 14):

Generally you would define both public *and* private functions in the `.cpp` file.

One reason to define functions in the `.h` file is if you want them to be inlineable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are concerned about `private` functions should be private with the meaning of "not visible in the header (which is the interface)". 
But `private` means "not accessible from outside the class", i.e. only functions of the class can call `private` functions.
If you don't want (human) users of your class see these implementation details, you need to use a suitable design patterns (facade pattern e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Defining in `.h` means inline, but defining in `.cpp` and using forward declaration, you can make your compilation more efficient.

See here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration